# Replacing hotend without replacing extruder assembly?

Tags: lulzbot

I have a Lulzbot TAZ 5, and the hotend is broken. Is there any way for me to replace the hotend without replacing the extruder motor and all surrounding parts?[image]

Comment: Could you possibly try to explain by [edit] what is exactly broken? Is it the thermistor, the heater element, the heater block, the heat break (metal tube that connects the heater block to the cooling fins) or the cooling fins? It could well be that you don't require a whole new hot end set, it depends on what's broken.

Comment: What @0scar said. You're probably looking for a thermistor or heater cartridge. The only other real possibilities for "broken" are stripped threads in the block (needs a new block) or bent/broken/threads-damaged heatbreak.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to replace the hot end, there are [descriptions](https://ohai.lulzbot.com/project/LulzBot-Hexagon-Hot-End-subassemblies/) available that [describe](https://www.printyourmind3d.ca/blogs/tutorials/replacing-the-hot-end-on-your-lulzbot-taz-printer) how to service or replace the "Mini Hexagon Hot End" or known as ["LulzBot LongBlock Hexagon Hot End Kit"](https://lulzbot.com/store/lulzbot-longblock-hexagon-hot-end-kit-1-2mm-kt-cp0112?ref=KT-CP0112).

However, it might be a challenge to find these hot ends to be sold separately. You need to search for "Hexagon hotend" and may find a [supplier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QM2BH8K) or [two](https://itworks3d.com/product/hexagon-hotend-assembly-2/) to acquire one.

It might be cheaper and more robust for the future to replace the extruder/hot end assembly all together. If you look at the amount of hits you get for the Hexagon extruder it appears as if it is discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I Stumbled into this while researching new nozzles for my dual extruder:
https://www.printyourmind3d.ca/blogs/tutorials/replacing-the-hot-end-on-your-lulzbot-taz-printer

This may do what you need.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The only link in the link you provided that navigates to the actual hotend serves a dead page. This probably implies that the hotend is end-of-life. Although this answer does answer the question, as in it provides a link to a workscope to replace the hotend, merely linking to such a site is not how a question should be answered. If the link dies due to link rot, the answer is not useful anymore.

Comment: Link only answers are not the way the stack works. -1